# htaccess rewrite rule not rewriting correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to change this:

http://example.com/profile.php?name=john

to

http://example.com/john

However it isn't working. It's displaying profile.php as my GET. Any ideas?

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L] # Profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,B,QSA]

this ended up working. had to remove to starting / but it works. thanks!

Comment: Yeah.. there was a typo! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```